# How to export a certain number of MySql databases with one command

Tags: mysql

I need to export around 20 databases in a MySql server which contain around 100 different databases, is it possible to export a list of database names into separate files using a console command? (under Linux of course).

Answer (score 3):

```
echo "show databases" | mysql -N | while read db
do
  mysqldump ${db} > ${db}.sql
done
```

You could use `grep` to remove unwanted databases like `mysql` and `information_schema`

Answer (score 2):

Create a text file with the name of each database you want to backup on it's own line

e.g.

```
db1
reports
```

Then use a script like this

```
#!/bin/bash
ERRORS=0

while read db
do
    echo "Processing $db"
    mysqldump -u root -p365576dx "$db" >"$db".sql
    EXITSTATUS=$?
    if [ "$ERRORS" -eq "0" -a "$EXITSTATUS" -ne "0" ]
    then
       ERRORS="$EXITSTATUS"
    fi

done<dbstodump

if [ "$ERRORS" -ne "0" ]
then
    echo "Errors occurred see above for details"
    exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution would be a simple for loop right on the command line. In my examples I want to export the databases `cars`, `animals` and `computers`.

```
for db in cars animals computers ; do mysqldump -uuser -ppassword "$db" > "$db.sql" ; done
```